# javascript Array.push({y: yValue, label: myLabel}) setting random "x" key value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an canvasJS, JavaScript Bar Charts, with the following functions,

```
    var dataPoints = [];
    var headers;
    var groups = [];
    var cityWide = 0;

    var chart = createChart();

    function createChart(title = "Hospitalized Count") {
        return new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            animationEnabled: true,
            
            title:{
                text:"Coronavirus Data in NYC Boroughs"
            },
            axisX:{
                interval: 1
            },
            axisY2:{
                interlacedColor: "rgba(1,77,101,.2)",
                gridColor: "rgba(1,77,101,.1)",
                title: "Total number of "+title
            },
            data: [{
                type: "bar",
                name: "companies",
                axisYType: "secondary",
                color: "#014D65",
                dataPoints: dataPoints
            }]
        });
    }
```

I am using this function below to set the dataPoints array:

function call: `dataPoints = setDataPoints(4)`

```
    function setDataPoints(value){
        let temp = [];
        for(var i = 0; i<groups.length;i++){
            if(groups[i][0] == "Citywide"){
                continue;
            }
            yValue = groups[i][value];
            myLabel = groups[i][0];
            
            console.log("y: "+ yValue);
            console.log("label: "+ myLabel);
            temp.push(
            {
                y: yValue, 
                label: myLabel
            });
        } 
        console.log(temp);
        return temp;

    }
```

But when i console.log(dataPoints) I am getting this:

```
[
    {"y": "136319","label": "Bronx","x": 0},
    {"y": "202778","label": "Brooklyn","x": 1},
    {"y": "97006","label": "Manhattan","x": 2},
    {"y": "202737","label": "Queens","x": 3},
    {"y": "54479","label": "StatenIsland","x": 4}
]
```

the expected result for dataPoints should be as follows:

```
[
        {y:136319, label: "Bronx" },
        {y:202778, label: "Brooklyn" },
        {y:97006, label: "Manhattan" },
        {y:202737, label: "Queens" },
        {y:54479, label: "StatenIsland" }|
]
```

When I tried to set x

```
temp.push(
{
  x: "123",
  y: yValue, 
  label: myLabel
});
```

or delete temp[i]['x'] it doesn't work.

As you may of notice the x value are the indexes of the array, I have no idea why its being set and how do I even remove.

I have tried

```
dataPoints = temp;
console.log(dataPoints[0].hasOwnProperty('x'));
```

and returns false

Any help would appreciate it thanks in advance!

**EDIT based of comment:**

in for loop:
`console.log(temp[i]['x'])` returns `undefined`

If I add in to temp.push({ x: "123", ...})
`console.log(temp[i]['x'])` returns `123`

console.log(temp[i]):

```
{y: "54479", label: "StatenIsland"}
label: "StatenIsland"
x: 4
y: "54479"
__proto__: Object
function.js:98
```

Comment: so... when you `console.log(temp[i]["x"])`, you get?

Comment: Oops sorry removed previous comment that was console.log(temp[i]) without the X, updated post with the results; ``console.log(temp[i]["x"] returns undefined``

Comment: Should we trust what is being passed into your function... that is `value` is being output correctly?

Comment: yes, value is currently set to 4 as a placeholder in another function where the function is being called.

Comment: It looks like you could take out everything below `dataPoints = temp` (put them after the function call for `setDataPoints`) and just straight up return temp instead of `dataPoints`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CanvasJS but my guess is that it's mutating the dataPoints array you give it to fill in the 'x' coordinate on the chart. console.log doesn't run synchronously, so by the time you see the output it's already been mutated.

If you `console.log([...dataPoints])` or `console.log([...temp])` I bet the `x` won't be there.

According to the [API docs for dataPoints.x](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-options/data/datapoints/x/):

> If not provided, it will be set automatically set according to its index position on dataPoints Array.

If you want to keep your "clean" copy of `dataPoints` you need to pass a copy of the array to the chart `[...dataPoints]`.

Comment: console.log([...dataPoints]) or console.log([...temp]) still gives me the x value =\, sadly, the x value won't let me draw the chart, was hoping to find a way to get rid of it, ill refer to the docs a bit (prob upvote if there a solution in doc)